# Laplace Domain Representation for Phase Detector

Tags: signal-processing, transfer-function, pll, laplace-transform

I am trying to model an LTI system and determine the overall transfer function of the system. The setup consists of a laser signal being fed through some filters, amplifiers, etc. represented by transfer function 1 (TF1) which is then mixed with a local oscillator by a phase detector. This mixed signal passes through a few more components represented by transfer function 2 and is then used as an output signal.

The trouble that I am having is with the representation of the local oscillator in the Laplace domain. The mixed signal leaving the phase detector is given by $$U_m = K[\theta_{m}(s)] = K[\theta_{lsr}(s) - \theta_{LO}(s)]$$
Where $\theta_{m}(s)$ is the phase difference between the two signals of the phase detector. How would I represent this phase signal from the local oscillator in the Laplace domain?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRaSjF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two signals having different phases, and you need them translated into Laplace domain:

$$\begin{align}
a(t)&=K_a\cos(\omega_a t+\phi_a)\tag{1} \\
b(t)&=K_b\cos(\omega_b t+\phi_b)\tag{2} \\
\mathcal{L}\Bigl\{a(t)\Bigr\}&=K_a\dfrac{\cos\phi_a s-\omega_a\sin\phi_a}{s^2+\omega_a^2}\tag{3} \\
\mathcal{L}\Bigl\{b(t)\Bigr\}&=K_b\dfrac{\cos\phi_b s-\omega_b\sin\phi_b}{s^2+\omega_b^2}\tag{4}
\end{align}$$

The signal is (3)-(4), and if the frequencies are different it will be a 3rd order transfer function, otherwise it all reduces to a simple difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. From what I've read, the particular shape of the waveform is irrelevant because the PD is a digital component and so it is only sensitive to the transitions of the oscillation signals, so the reference oscillator can be represented by its phase only. How would the phase only representation look in the Laplace domain? Or even in general.

Comment: @Inf_E I think it's represented with a simple \$K\phi\$. After all, a generic transfer function shows:$$G(s)=\dfrac{K_{\phi}\cdot K_{VCO}\cdot F(s)}{s}$$ Which shows \$F(s)/s\$ as the only Laplace term. The error is supposed to be a DC signal proportional to the phase, so \$K_{\phi}\$ makes sense.

Comment: So is it incorrect then to say that if frequency is the derivative of phase by $$\omega = \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$ $$\omega t = \phi$$ Then the laplace representation of the phase would be $$L[\omega t] = \frac{\omega}{s^2}$$

Comment: @Inf_E No, in fact, that's similar to what I've written, except the \$s\$ term in the numerator. Maybe that can be simplified, too, similar to merging \$\omega_a\rightarrow\omega_b\rightarrow\omega\$.